# Golang рассматривает пакет как модуль

Tags: golang, модули

Структура проекта:

```
src
|----project
    |----service
        |----service.go
    |----go.mod
    |----go.sum
    |----main.go
```

В качестве модуля используется модуль [pgx](https://github.com/jackc/pgx), в качестве пакета service - обычный пакет, который выводит текст на экран. Вот содержимое `service/service.go`:

```
package service

import (
    "fmt"
)

func SomeFunction(text string) {
    fmt.Println(text)
}
```

И содержимое `main.go`, который использует этот пакет:

```
package main

import (
    "project/service"
)

func main() {
    service.SomeFunction("Some text")
}
```

При попытке скомпилировать `go build -o $GOPATH/bin/project` выдаёт ошибку:

```
build mod: cannot load project/service: malformed module path "project/service": missing dot in first path element
```

... или на русском:

```
невозможно загрузить project/service: неверно сформирован путь к модулю "project/service": отсутствует точка в первом элементе пути
```

---

Почему Golang считает что мой пакет service - это модуль? Ведь в файле `go.mod` он не указан:

```
module mod

go 1.13

require github.com/jackc/pgx/v4 v4.2.1 // indirect
```

Как мне указать Go, что пакет service - это обычный пакет, а не модуль? Или если я  в проекте использую модули, то обязан подключать все пакеты как модули?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно было в файле `go.mod` заменить строку

```
module mod
```

на

```
module project
```

Потому что мой проект называется project, а не mod. После этого ошибка исчезает.

Answer (score 1):

Имя модуля должно выглядеть как ссылка, например go mod init github.com/path/to/module.
Сделано это, как я думаю для того, чтобы go get работал корректно.
Если вы не планируете выкладывать никуда свое приложение, напишите example.com/you/module

Comment: Если я в проекте использую какой-либо модуль, то теперь все свои пакеты для приложения я должен указывать как модули? Раньше я мог просто создать папку с пакетом внутри приложения, а теперь нет. Этот пакет - неотъемлемая часть приложения, почему я должен подключать его как модуль? Это же просто пакет.

Comment: свои пакеты не надо указывать как модули, как модуль надо указывать свое приложение.

Comment: Т.е. твое приложение будет example.com/you/project
Пакеты приложения будет example.com/you/project/service
Импорт: "example.com/you/project/service"
В го моде их прописывать не надо, т.к. при go get все сабпакеты сами посасываются

Comment: Так я и не указываю свои пакеты как модули. Но Go почему-то считает иначе и говорит, что мой пакет service (который внутри приложения) - это модуль. Хотя это не так. И я не могу понять, почему так происходит.